Clicking on "See More" in Facebook WITHOUT mouse on Firefox or Chrome
I tried using Ctrl+F, input "See More", Esc, then Enter, but it does not work.
What other keyboard shortcut can I used to trigger "See More" in Facebook for long posts? An extension or 3ʳᵈ party user script will be even better!

can tab and enter be used? most buttons can be tabbed to if window in focus.

The Software Recommendations portion of this question is off-topic here, but will be on-topic at Software Recommendations SE: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Keyboard shortcuts might vary depending on the keyboard layout among other things. Please specify what keyboard layout you are using, and make the question more specific, choose one ask for a keyboard shortcut or a extension or a user script. You might ask question about the other options. Please bear in mind that there is a site specialized on question asking for software recommendations: [softwarerecs.se].
